# Нужно ли писать слеш в конце тега input?

Tags: html

Какая из этих записей является более правильной?

`<input type="submit" value="Отправить">`

`<input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Без разницы. . .

Comment: смотря какому стандарту написания html следуете.

Comment: Не нужно, но можно. https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Разницы нет, но обычно лучше обходиться без самозакрывающегося тега в html воизбежание возможных проблем и юзать первый способ.
Можешь почитать про самозакрывающиеся теги в html [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/252283/)